# Why Visual Studio Code and Atom formats differently with prettier?

Tags: visual-studio-code, atom-editor, prettier

I have both app in my Mac. I have a `.prettierrc` file. Save do the formatting and the two IDE formats differently. Why?

If I run prettier from console, like: `prettier --write .` that one will not change Atom, only Visual Studio Code. What is wrong with VS Code?

```
{
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": false
}
```

Not much change, but long lines are kept be VS Code, and broken by Atom / console.

Comment: VS Code isn't an IDE, it's best described as _an editor_ (though the differences between the two get blurrier every year...)

Comment: VS Code should be using `.editorconfig`  which I think overrides `prettier` - what's your `.editorconfig` situation like?

Comment: I do not have any `.editorconfig`  at the root of my repo.

Comment: `.editorconfig` files have a very large scope on your filesystem. An `.editorconfig` file can be in an far, far ancestor directory, outside any repo, and still be used by the editor.

Comment: I found one in `node_modules` is it normal it is there? How can I stop it to have any effect?

Comment: VS Code treats the current project as top-level, so `.editorconfig` on a higher level will be ignored